# DAX: Joining records within the same table to perform ratio calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I have a table with three columns: Date, Store_ID, and Event.  The event column have Event A's and Event B's: there is a 1:1 relationship between Events A and B, however, each Event A may not have an Event B.  The events associated with a Store_ID can occur over different time periods.

I want to perform a calculation of the ratio of count of Event_B_Numerator to count of Event_A_Denominator for all Store_IDs subject to the Date context associated to Event A records (i.e., if my date filter is set to December 2021, I want the count of all records with Event A in December 2021 as the denominator, and the count of all Event B records associated to the same Store_IDs as the Event A records, regardless of when the Event B records occurred).

Here is how the data table looks:

'Store_Events'

| Date | Store_ID | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/01/2021 | 1 | Event A |
| 12/01/2021 | 1 | Event A |
| 12/01/2021 | 2 | Event A |
| 12/01/2021 | 3 | Event A |
| 12/01/2021 | 3 | Event B |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 | Event B |
| 01/01/2022 | 2 | Event A |

In this table, Store 1 has 2 Event A's in December and 1 Event B for Store 1 all time - ratio is 50%; Store 2 has 1 Event A in December and 0 Event B for Store 2 all time - ratio is 0%; Store 3 has 1 Event A in December and 1 Event B for Store 3 all time - ratio is 100%.

Here is how I'm thinking to solve in DAX:

```
VAR event_A_tab = CALCULATETABLE ('Store_Events','Store_Events'[Event] == "Event A")

VAR event_B_tab = CALCULATETABLE (ALL('Store_Events'),'Store_Events'[Event] == "Event B")

VAR joined_tab = NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN (event_A_tab,event_B_tab)

VAR count_A_events = COUNTROWS (joined_tab','joined_tab'[Event] == "Event A")

VAR count_B_events = COUNTROWS (joined_tab','joined_tab'[Event] == "Event B")

RETURN
    DIVIDE (count_B_events,count_A_events,0)
```

Is this the correct/most efficient way to approach this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Made an edit to the paragraph describing how to calculate the ratio

Answer (score 0):

This should be a better solution for your case:

```
Ratio = 
var _selectedmonth = SELECTEDVALUE(ratio[Month])
var _selectedStore_ID = SELECTEDVALUE(ratio[Store_ID])
var _countEventA = CALCULATE( countrows(ratio), FILTER(ALL(ratio), ratio[Month] = _selectedmonth && ratio[Store_ID] = _selectedStore_ID && ratio[Event]="Event A")) +0
var _countEventBALLTime = CALCULATE( countrows(ratio), FILTER(ALL(ratio), ratio[Store_ID] = _selectedStore_ID && ratio[Event]="Event B"))+0

return
 DIVIDE(_countEventBALLTime, _countEventA)+0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that out.

Comment: will this only work when slicing in context by the individual store id and dates?  What if there is no filter on dates so it should cover all time?

Comment: You can modify this measure. instead of ALL(ratio), specify columns where you want to remove filter or on which column you want to keep (use ALLEXCEPT);  here example

Ratio = 
var _selectedStore_ID = SELECTEDVALUE(ratio[Store_ID])
var _countEventA = CALCULATE( countrows(ratio), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(ratio[Month]),  ratio[Store_ID] = _selectedStore_ID && ratio[Event]="Event A")) +0
var _countEventBALLTime = CALCULATE( countrows(ratio), FILTER(ALL(ratio), ratio[Store_ID] = _selectedStore_ID && ratio[Event]="Event B"))+0

return
 DIVIDE(_countEventBALLTime, _countEventA)+0